# Dagger fails after migrating to 2.17

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I've two modules `:app` and `:settings`. Here are my dagger configuration.

My component:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        RoutingModule::class,
        SettingsModule::class
    ]
)
interface ELanguageComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): ELanguageComponent
    }

    fun inject(application: BaseELanguageApplication)
}
```

The `RoutingModule`:

```
@Module
class RoutingModule {

    @Provides
    fun ProvidesettingsFragmentRouter(router: SettingsRouter): SettingsFragment.Router = router
}
```

The `SettingsRouter`:

```
class SettingsRouter @Inject constructor(
    private val applicationStateManager: ApplicationStateManager
) : SettingsFragment.Router
```

The `SettingsModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class SettingsModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SettingsFragmentModule::class, ApplicationStateManagerModule::class])
    abstract fun settingsActivity(): SettingsActivity
}

@Module
abstract class ApplicationStateManagerModule {

    @Module
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun bindApplicationStateManager(settingsActivity: SettingsActivity): ApplicationStateManager = settingsActivity
    }
}
```

My `SettingsFragmentModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class SettingsFragmentModule {

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun settingsFragment(): SettingsFragment
}
```

And the `SettingsFragment.Router` is injected inside my `SettingsFragment`:

```
class SettingsFragment : DaggerFragment() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var router: Router
  
  ...
}
```

I've already found and read [this article](https://github.com/google/dagger/wiki/Dagger-2.17-@Binds-bugs) but it does not help much since the error is not that explanatory:

> [Dagger/MissingBinding]
> com.altissia.common.authentication.ApplicationStateManager cannot be
> provided without an @Provides-annotated method. public abstract
> interface ELanguageComponent {
> ^
> com.altissia.common.authentication.ApplicationStateManager is injected at
> com.altissia.router.SettingsRouter(applicationStateManager, …)
> com.altissia.router.SettingsRouter is injected at
> com.altissia.injection.module.RoutingModule.ProvidesettingsFragmentRouter(router)
> com.altissia.settings.fragment.SettingsFragment.Router is injected at
> com.altissia.settings.fragment.SettingsFragment.router
> com.altissia.settings.fragment.SettingsFragment is injected at
> dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.altissia.injection.component.ELanguageComponent →
> com.altissia.settings.injection.module.SettingsModule_SettingsActivity.SettingsActivitySubcomponent
> →
> com.altissia.settings.injection.module.SettingsFragmentModule_SettingsFragment.SettingsFragmentSubcomponent]

What am I missing here? `ApplicationStateManager` is provided through the `ApplicationStateManagerModule` which is installed inside `SettingsModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation in the linked article applies here.

- `SettingsFragment` requests a `SettingsFragment.Router`.
- `SettingsFragment.Router` depends on `SettingsRouter`, and this binding is in the application component.
- `SettingsRouter` depends on `ApplicationStateManager` via an `@Inject` constructor.
- The `ApplicationStateManager` binding is in your (generated) activity subcomponent.

Thus, you have a binding in the parent component which requires a binding in a subcomponent.  As described in the article, the easiest way to fix this is to move `RoutingModule` into your activity (or fragment) subcomponent.

Answer (score 0):

You should add SettingsFragment to SettingsActivity using a contributor module

```
    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
       ApplicationStateManagerModule::class, 
       FragmentContributorModule::class])
    abstract fun settingsActivity(): SettingsActivity
```

And contributor module is something like this

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentContributorModule {

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SettingsFragmentModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeSettingsFragment(): SettingsFragment
}
```

My setup that i used to use with dagger-android was

AppComponent

```
    @Component(modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        ActivityContributorModule::class])
    /*
     * ActivityContributorModule defines which Activities will have which modules and inject objects
     * If an Activity has any fragments it should add them via FragmentContributorModule with @ContributesAndroidInjector
     * @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainActivityModule.class, FragmentContributorModule.class})
     */
 @Singleton
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    override fun inject(myApplication: MyApplication)

}
```

and Activity set up with `ActivityContributorModule`

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityContributorModule {
    
    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class, FragmentContributorModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SecondActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeSecondActivity(): SecondActivity
    
    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeThirdActivity(): ThirdActivity
}
```

And for the fragments to be used by Activities

@Module

```
abstract class FragmentContributorModule {
    /**
     * FragmentContributorModule is used inside ActivityContributorModule
     * With @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MyFragmentModule.class)
     * defines which module will be used to inject objects to MyFragment
     *
     *
     * In this example [MainActivity] has [FirstFragment] fragment1, and [FirstFragment]
     * uses [FirstFragmentModule] to inject objects
     *
     *
     *
     * Scope of @ContributesAndroidInjector methods and their modules should be same.
     * Otherwise app returns HAS CONFLICTING SCOPES error
     *
     */
    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FirstFragmentModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMyFragment(): FirstFragment
}
```

This is obsolete since the Dagger Hilt came out. It's much easier to implement dependency injection.

You can check out this [github link](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Dagger2-Tutorials) you can refer both for dagger-android with scoped components or Hilt implementations.